# How to list simples for configurables?

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, simple-product

How should it look like in the Magento Admin, if I have added some configurable attributes and/or simple products to a configurable?

I am trying to add simples to my configurable programmatically, and do not know how to test it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it should look like in Magento Admin, when simple products are linked to a configurable product:

[image: Screenshot of simple/configurable links in Magento Admin 2.2]

Answer (score 0):

Create a test product manually and compare it with the programmatically created one.

Comment: Thank you, the answer is definitely correct, but I had difficulties to do that (despite following the instructions in the Magento documentation). The assistant offered me to add even configurable products to a configurable product, and when I added a simple, it would not ask me about the attributes. I therefore would not know, if everything was added the right way. Just needed an example. ;)